# Auth::attempt() does not return anything

Tags: authentication, laravel-4

I'm using laravel 4.
This is my Seeder

```
User::create(array(
        'name'     => 'Rubber Gajulu',
        'username' => 'awesome',
        'email'    => 'awesome@awe.com',
        'password' => Hash::make('awesome'),
    ));
```

And this is where I am testing the Auth::attempt() function

```
Route::get('testlogin',function(){

$userdata = ['email'=> 'awesome@awe.com','password'=> 'awesome'];

echo Auth::attempt($userdata);

if (Auth::attempt($userdata))
    echo 'SUCCESS!';
else
    echo 'FAILURE!';
});
```

It just returns FAILURE. The first echo does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller code is wrong. It should be this:

```
Route::get('testlogin',function(){

$userdata = ['email'=> 'awesome@awe.com','password'=> 'awesome'];

if (Auth::attempt($userdata))
    echo 'SUCCESS!';
else
    echo 'FAILURE!';
});
```

Otherwise in your current code you are trying to login the user twice, so the second one fails.

Comment: I tried this code.. No luck. I still get the same error

Comment: post your user model code? and are you sure the user is actually seeded in your database?

Comment: Yeah I checked phpmyadmin. I did not make any changes to the default user model

Answer (score 0):

Check if logs/laravel.log shows any error on hitting this url.

Share that.

Comment: No Errors in the log file

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found my mistake
Thanks to Isabell Knauers [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20569346/1451920)

My model had

```
$table->string('password',32)
```

Data was being truncated to 32 characters. Now I changed it to

```
$table->string('password',100)
```

and everything works as intended